# Error : function_clause while running the docker container for the rabbitmq

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I do see the following error message on running the RabitMQ image:

```
echo "Setting up rabbitmq"
Setting up rabbitmq
docker exec rabbitmq \
        rabbitmqctl add_user  
Error: function_clause
make: *** [config] Error 2
```

How can I troubleshoot that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you have ran that container.
Try it interactively:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint bash dockerfile/rabbitmq:latest
[ root@0c5920d3559e:/data ]$ rabbitmq-start
```

If it is still not working, try and switch to the [Docker official RabbitMQ image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/) (with its [github repo](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq)), and see if it works better.